# How to sort WorkQueues by both size and last activity?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, priority-queue

I want to put a small number (10~50) of WorkQueues in a PriorityQueue (or a CircularQueue) and sort them (1) normally by size (2) but to avoid starving WorkQueues with small amount of accumulated work, I'd like to bump their rank once they haven't been served for say 200 milliseconds.

I can live with a round robin scheduling algorithm by using a CircularQueue instead of a PriorityQueue, however if most of the WorkQueues are normally empty, then searching for the next busy WorkQueue is not very efficient.

By using a PriorityQueue, I can have a comparison function like below,

```
// Use C++ to demonstrate the idea, my working language is actually Java
struct cmp {
    bool operator<(const WorkQueue& a, const WorkQueue& b) {
       if ( /* both a and b were last served within 200 ms */ )
           return a.size() < b.size(); // Pick the queue with larger size
       else
           return a.age() < b.age(); // Pick the queue that has not been served longer
    }
};
```

The problem here is that (1) work items are being popped out of a work queue and the last served timestamp gets updated from time to time and (2) when we calculate age(), we may have to get the current time repeatedly and this may cause the sorting in the PriorityQueue to be unstable, and this is a big no-no.

Any suggestions? Could there be a simple scoring system that takes account of both work queue size and age?

Comment: The size can also change after the workqueue is put in the priorityqueue, right?  So the size comparison isn't valid either?

Comment: @MattTimmermans No, everytime a workitem is added to a workqueue, the workequeue is popped first then after the workitem is added, the workqueue is pushed back onto the priorityqueue again.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, you can't really solve this problem with a single priority queue, because the passage of time can change the relative priorities of many items and you don't want to have to reorder the whole queue every few ms.

I would probably do it with two priority queues:

- in PQs, which is ordered by descending size, you add an entry (workqueue, size) when a work queue goes non-empty, or when its size grows to at least 120% of the its largest entry in the queue.  The smaller entries can remain in the queue to be popped later.
- in PQt, which is ordered by ascending service time, you add an entry (workqueue, time) when the queue goes non-empty.

The entries in the priority queue never change.  When it's time to perform a task, if the first entry in PQt is >= 200ms old, then pop that.  Otherwise, pop PQs.

In either case, if the entry is still valid, i.e., if the work queue is still bigger than the size from PQs, or it still hasn't been serviced since the time in PQt, then you can perform the task.

Either way, when you remove an entry from PQt, you should reschedule it with its real last service time if the queue is non-empty and it doesn't have a queued entry.

Using two queues like this, the sequence of *valid* entries you pop from the pair of queues is the sequence in which you want to execute tasks.

For extra points, note that java priority queues really aren't the best data structure to use for either of these queues.  For PQt, it would be better to use a timing wheel.  (read this. It's lots of fun: https://blog.acolyer.org/2015/11/23/hashed-and-hierarchical-timing-wheels/).  For PQs it would be better to use an array of size buckets.

Comment: I like the idea of having two queues.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something with a [min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap)? For example, you make a rule that anything older than five minutes gets re-prioritized. Then, any time you insert something into the queue, you also check the back of the queue to see if there are entries older than five minutes. You remove them from the queue and re-insert them.

Your comparison method would have to use some function that combines age and size to come up with a single priority value.

I've done something similar to (although not exactly like) this in the past, and found it pretty effective. Efficiency will depend on the size of your queue and how often jobs are backed up in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

My current plan is to use two TreeSet's to store the work queues by size and absolute expiry time. For both TreeSet / PriorityQueue, getting the top element is O(1). For both insertion and removal of an element from the TreeSet, the complexity is O(logN), PriorityQueue should be the same, although I am not sure about removal, I hope it's not O(N).

Comment: I read the source code and unfortunately PriorityQueue.remove() is O(N).

Comment: It's not terribly difficult to build a custom priority queue that keeps track of nodes in the heap. It's called an indexed priority queue. Doing this with a heap-based queue is kind of messy, but not terribly difficult. It's easier with a skip list or a pairing heap.